# Object-Oriented Programming: Why "Oriented"?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology, history, grammar

I am most of the way through my games programming degree.  This is not a computer science degree, so a lot of the theory is eschewed in favour of practical portfolio building and what I see as JIT learning, which is apparently more important in the games industry.  The first subject was "Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming".

That phrase didn't bother me until I learned about the different programming paradigms (I'm getting this list from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms):

- Imperative
- Functional
- Procedural
- Structured
- Event-Driven
- Object-Oriented
- Declarative
- Automata-Based

I get that this is not an exhaustive list, and that not all of these concepts are equal, and most of them aren't even exclusive, but I don't understand why most of them get just one word - imperative; functional; declarative - but when we talk about programming with objects, we have to clarify that we are *oriented* around those objects.  Can't we just *use* objects?  Can't we just *have* objects?  Why must they *orient* us, as our guiding star?

Looking here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), nowhere is the use of the term "oriented" addressed as its own term.  Only "object" is explained.

Also, I can see for practical reasons why Event-Driven is used, because Event Programming is already a thing that you do when you're running a conference, and Automata Programming makes it sound like you're setting up a robotic production line, so it helps to have additional clarifying words there.

**What makes Object Programming, as a phrase, not enough to describe what we do when we use objects in our programming?**

Obviously from my tone I'm not too fond of the word "oriented".  It reminds me of my time as a court reporter, listening to lawyer after lawyer use the phrase "in relation to" as a kind of verbal tick.  It didn't mean anything; it was just a term that they used to fill the air while they tried to think of what to say next.  However, I'm not trying to advocate a change of language, I'm just asking why it is the way it is.  If someone knows why it came to be known that way for purely historical, vestigial reasons, then that's the answer.  It will be ammunition if I ever decide to waste my time advocating for a change of language.

On the other hand, if there is actually a useful reason for why a language or piece of code must *point* towards objects, to the exclusion of all other directions, as opposed to merely having them in its toolbelt, as *tools*, I would really be interested to learn about it.  I like learning useful things.

Comment: I guess "Objectively" or "Objectional" would not give the right impression of what is really meant ;-)

Comment: I considered "Objectified", but decided that might give off the wrong vibes too.

Comment: Related: [What did they call Object-Oriented Programming before Alan Kay invented the term?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142327/what-did-they-call-object-oriented-programming-before-alan-kay-invented-the-term)

Comment: I think "object" is the mistake, not "oriented". What we call object-oriented is usually class-oriented.

Comment: @Steve314 - I think an object as an instance of a class is a very useful metaphor for the way OO programming works.  A "class" is already an abstract concept, so using it as the basis for understanding another abstract concept loses much of the intuitive power of the object metaphor.

Comment: Any Phoenix Wright fans want to just call it "OBJECTION!! Programming"?

Comment: Programming can be object-oriented but most programming that is called object-oriented is class-oriented. I don't think it would be a mistake to call it class-oriented.

Comment: @Steve314 Not really. There are languages that have a concept of an *object*, but they don't use the concept of a *class*, one notable example being pre-ES6 JavaScript.

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc - "usually" doesn't mean "always", though certainly the meaning of "OOP" seems to have shifted over time - because everyone wanted to be on that bandwagon and stretching definitions was sometimes the only way. I prefer Haskells attitude to OOP - it has classes but they're not OOP classes, it's just how Haskell does polymorphism and interface-based programming. The term "class" (as in "class of types") was more appropriate before classes could have multiple arguments etc. Haskell proudly doesn't claim to be OOP.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you're reading *way* too much into a simple grammatical construct. Take a look at your list of paradigms, sorted differently for a reason we will get to shortly:

- Imperative
- Functional
- Procedural
- Structured
- Declarative
- Event-Driven
- Automata-Based
- Object-Oriented

What do the words all have in common? They're all adjectives because they're intended to modify the word "programming". Furthermore, with the exception of "imperative" they're all not "natural" adjectives, but "adjectified" nouns - nouns that actually describe the core of the paradigm: function, structure, automata, and object.

And there are two different ways in which the nouns are adjectified: through a suffix like -al or -ed, or through creating a composite word using a hyphen. Now, as Doc Brown has pointed out, the suffixes that could be used to adjectify "object" result in a different meaning. Which leaves composition.

And I submit that it is pure coincidence or taste that Alan Kay chose to use "oriented" for his composite adjective "object-oriented". It could just as well have been "object-driven", or "object-based", and you might read too much into those as well. Doesn't "driven" sound like some sort of unhealthy obsession?

Comment: Excellent point (although I think you mean adjectives, not adverbs -- "programming" in this context is a noun).

Comment: @JW01: oops, you're right

Comment: This is actually a very good point - the word "oriented" gives the phrase different meaning to "object programming", because the word "object" by itself isn't an adjective.  Actually, I'd say the reason "oriented" was picked over other words was for the alliteration.  Also, I wasn't reading anything into it, I was exaggerating to make the point that there's this word "oriented" that sits there completely unexplained and unquestioned in the literature, which made me wonder if it was actually doing anything to earn its spot. :P

Comment: Wonder why he didn't choose object-obsessed... oh yeah, those are only the zealots who don't know when to stop. ;-)

Comment: There is one book by a Polish author, Jerzy Grębosz, called "Symfonia C++" ("The Symphony in C++") in which the author tries to make some sense out of that phrase in an interesting way: He says that it is called "object-oriented" because of the fact that the code can "orient itself" according to the object it is currently working with (polymorphic behaviour). He distinguishes this from the languages in which there's just a mere concept of "objects" as pieces of data. There's no historical evidence that this was the original meaning, but it's quite explanatory even as a post-factum explanation.

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc: Heh. In fiction, we'd call that a "retcon".

Answer (score 18):

> but when we talk about programming with objects, we have to clarify that we are oriented around those objects. Can't we just use objects? Can't we just have objects?

Frankly, it's a holdover of history. Functional programming is really function-oriented programming, declarative programming is really declaration-oriented programming... after all don't we just use functions? Can't we just have functions?

"Object oriented" rolls off the tongue better, and is historically ingrained.

The 'orientation' comes because we're not talking about programming but design. Just because we use objects, or use functions, or use events does not mean that our design methodology is done by modelling all three. By specifying the orientation of the design methodology, it helps communicate to programmers how they should interpret and extend that design - how the modelling focus colors the implementation.

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying that "object-oriented" is a kind of policy statement with redundant phrasing, just like "pro-active" has essentially the same meaning as "active", it's just got a redundant prefix attached to make sure the listener doesn't miss the meaning.

Comment: I think you really hit the nail on that one: We do Object-oriented design, and that is why the languages are object-oriented - to allow us to express this design.

Comment: @Excrubulent No, adding the "oriented" makes it more specific. "Object oriented" means we're not discussing specifics about programming objects, but instead on how to design programs so they use objects in a meaningful way. "Object programming", "function programming" or "declaration programming" would refer to specifically talking about those specific concept implementation instead of design principles. "Functional" and "declarative" are words with suffixes that attempt to convey the same meaning, but for objects "objectial" or "objective" wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: And as [Michael Borgwardt answered](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/205542/12613), the word "oriented" isn't in any way special. It could be "driven" or "based" just as well. The important point is that it couldn't be "object programming". (Well laguange is always fluid, so it *could*, but it just woudn't be as descriptive.)

Comment: I've switched answers because Michael Borgwardt's answer actually explains the meaning of the word and how it modifies the phrase.

Comment: @Excrubulent "pro-active" and "active" are not the same. "Active" means that you are currently doing the action, or that you do it frequently, while "pro-active" means that you are not necessary doing it right now, but you are "oriented yourself towards (pro) doing it", or towards being active in general. That you support active way of life and that you approach this goal.

Answer (score 2):

Calling it that helps to explain that objects are a very important part of the paradigm.

Object-Oriented programming has its roots in [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula), which was essentially ALGOL plus some new object-programming features.  And in keeping with that history, even today it's entirely possible in many languages (even the "pure OO languages") to code something that is essentially just a procedural program with some objects in it.  But this is considered bad style by more experienced developers.

Actually doing something "the object-oriented way" is very different from "the procedural way."  The most important concept is the use of inheritance and polymorphism.  When you truly understand and *internalize* the way classes and virtual methods work, it's an eye-opening experience that changes the way you write code in a lot of cases, a true paradigm shift.  (Assuming, of course, that you started out writing procedural code first.  A lot of students these days go straight to Java or C# as a first language, and IMO they miss out on really understanding the benefits of OO by doing so.)

We call it object-oriented programming because a program written in OO style does not just contain objects; the structure of the whole program is based around them and around the way they work.

Comment: This is a similar answer to Telastyn's, except you seem to imply that "object-oriented programming " as a term is actually fundamentally different to "object programming".  Can you explain how they might be different?  I mean, it seems to me that OOP is a loose enough term that OP would serve the same function just as well.

Comment: A lot of students these days go straight to Java or C# as a first language, and IMO they miss out on really understanding the benefits of OO by doing so. - Actually, I started on C++, and in my first assignment I used a mix of objects and functions, but was marked down for my use of functions.  Some of those functions were purely functional, and didn't benefit at all from encapsulation in an object, but others that took pointers to variables in order to work (ie: modified state information), became much easier to make and call once they were in an object, so I've seen both sides of it.